# Workflow for Polling Application?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am currently working on a new application (.Net 3.5/Win2008 Server environment) that does a nightly poll of a database table to find records that need processing. Very simple process overall. Previously, I have used a Windows Service "Shell" app to do the timer/sleep/poll process.

My question is more of: Since I have the opportunity to start from scratch, would it make sense to turn this kind of an application into a WF Service? I haven't developed a feel for WF design yet, so I'm not sure if this would work, or even be a good use case for WF.

Would the timer event go in the WF itself, or be external to the WF and just start the WF as needed. If the external case is necessary, it might be better just to use my existing shell app.

Thanks for any suggestions or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could, but if it's a simple application, the only reason to do so would be as an excercise in learning WF.

Why don't you just schedule a task to execute at a certain time every day? It's a basic Windows feature. There is no need for a poll/sleep/poll application :)

Comment: The program is a little more complicated than the single task suggested. The program also exposes a WCF interface for an on demand excution. I didn't want to dilute the question by adding a lot of extra information. But yes, if it was a simple as stated, an 'at job' would be a good solution.